# Axis and Allies 1940, why are the axis always losing

Tags: axis-and-allies

I‘ve been playing A&A 1940 Europe (without Japan) and everytime the Axis Powers losses. I‘ve tried Sealion and stuff but its still everytime the same. At the beginning Germany is beating up france and some small parts of Russia but them the americans lands in europe and Germany cant hold it. What can i try to win with the Axis power?

Answer (score 1):

One strategy to deal with one side always losing is to have an auction to decide who gets which side: each person bids a certain amount of IPC. Whoever gives the highest bid takes the Allies, and the other person gets to place units equal to that bid at the start.

Comment: This also has the beauty of being self-adjusting amongst any (relatively) small group of regular players, as new strategies for each side are developed.